# Shortcut to see class hierarchy in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have one query that is I am using eclipse and I have imported the project and as usual in a project there are 30 to 40 packages and each package contains set of classes , Now say in package named A I have a class Named abc and in later subpackages ,let say in package named W i have extended and override some of the methods of that class(abc) and construct a new class named def which extend the parent class abc, now please let me let me know I have opened the parent class abc in eclipse is there any shortcut through which I can find out which subclasses in later package overrides it's method and which subclasses are extending it..!

Comment: `which subclasses are extending it` -> What do you mean by this statement? Do you mean overriding methods?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes: When your cursor is on the class name (as in: `public class A|bc`), you can press <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> to see the inheritance hierarchy of `Abc`.

Comment: Small addition: if your cursor does not happen to be on a specific class name Eclipse defaults to showing the hierarchy of the class in the main editor, which - if this is the desired hierarchy - might save some scrolling to the top of the class to position your cursor accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

If you press CTRL-T twice, it will show you the supertype hierarchy, which also includes any Interfaces that your class implements. Occasionally very useful.

Answer (score 6):

Also,

```
Right click on the file in the project explorer -> Open type hierarchy.
Same works for right click on the class name in editor window.
Shortcut is F4.
```

Comment: The `F4` shortcut really opens a View, not a Window

Answer (score 4):

Also, apart from worthy `shortcut` that `Aaron` posted, you can also do this: -

> Go to Windows -> Show Views -> Open Outline view (If not found - go to Others)

It will open an Outline View which shows your class hierarchy of your current class